# Message system - How to send a group e-mail but only list one e-mail in sentbox

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a personal messaging system using PHP and MySQL. Part of the system allows for the sending of group e-mails to people who fit within certain groups.

The code for sending the e-mail is:

```
session_start();
include_once('../../dbconnect.php');

$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$to = $_POST ['touser'];
$toemail = $_POST['touseremail'];
$from = $_SESSION['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$time = time();

if ($to == 'Level 4'){
 $usersquery = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE account = 'Level4'";
 $getusers = $conn -> query($usersquery);
 while ($row = $getusers->fetch_assoc()){

  foreach ($row as $value){

 $query ="INSERT INTO messages (to_user, to_email, subject, message, from_user, from_email, daterecord) VALUES ('" . $to . "', '" . $value . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $subject) . "', '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $message) . "', '$from', '$email', '$time')";
   $send = $conn -> query($query);

  }

 }

}
```

This works fine, but the problem is when I open the sentbox, each individual message is displayed - when a large group has been messaged, this clogs up the sentbox and is very annoying! The code for the sentbox is:

```
$emailquery = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_email = '$email' AND sent_deleted = 'no' ORDER BY daterecord DESC";
$sentemails = $conn->query($emailquery);
$emailcount = $sentemails ->num_rows;

if ($emailcount == 0){
 echo '<div>No messages sent</div>';
}

else{
?>
<table class="udtable">
    <tr>
        <th class="reqhead">To</th>
        <th class="reqhead">Subject</th>
        <th class="reqhead"></th>
    </tr>
<?
$i=1;
while ($sent = $sentemails->fetch_assoc()){
if ($i%2 != 0){
        $rowclass = 'reqodd';
        }
        else {
        $rowclass = 'reqeven';
        }

 echo ' <tr class = "' . $rowclass . '">
         <td class="reqfrom">' . $sent['to_user'] . '</td>
         <td class="reqsubj">' . $sent['subject'] . '</td>
         <td class="req"><a id="link' . $sent['id'] . '" href="#" class="sentopen">Open</a></td>
         <td class="reqmessage"><pre class=sentboxmessage>' . $sent['message'] . '</pre></td>
         <td class="reqid">' . $sent['id'] . '</td>
        </tr>';
        $i++;
}

?>
</table>
<?
}

?>
```

The sentbox looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to consolidate all of those messages into a single line.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: For a single email, use a BCC. Otherwise send one email per-person.

Comment: You could add a unique message ID to each "group" of emails you send, and only return one message with your second query, based on the message ID. Alternatively, you could add all the names to the same message; but then you need a field with "allUsers" which will be a bit messy. Just some thoughts.

Comment: @MarcB - I think the user's point is that he implemented his own email system with a database that doesn't have a concept of group distribution - let alone cc and bcc capability. Chris - can you confirm my understanding?

Comment: So is the problem that you actually want to send a single email, or is the problem that you want to have a way to group related emails within your "sent box" display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use grouping in your mysql select statement in your sentbox code snippet

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_email = '$email' AND sent_deleted = 'no' GROUP BY subject, daterecord ORDER BY daterecord DESC
```

This will work and will group your messages by the subject and by the daterecord. So any messages that are sent all at the same time with the same subject will be grouped together. You might need to add in more grouping options to refine if multiple people could send messages with the same subject at the same time.